# How do you push child elements of an object into an array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a promise from a Google People API, and I want to create an array from portions of the data. I cannot figure out how to make child elements in the array.

```
let arr = new Array();

for (var a = 0; a < obj.length; a++) {
    arr.push(obj[a].requestedResourceName);
    for (var b = 0; b < obj[a].person.names.length; b++) {
        if (obj[a].person.names[b].metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT') {
            arr[a].push(obj[a].person.names[b]);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is: **Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: arr[a].push is not a function**

Comment: console log `arr[a]`

Comment: post k4kItems array values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding something that is not an array to `arr[a]` when you do  `arr.push(this.k4kItems[a].requestedResourceName)`.

One suggestion would be to add an object containing a children property

```
let arr = new Array();

for (var a = 0; a < this.k4kItems.length; a++) {
  // Adding object with children array
  arr.push({item: this.k4kItems[a].requestedResourceName, children: []});
  for (var b = 0; b < this.k4kItems[a].person.names.length; b++) {
    if (this.k4kItems[a].person.names[b].metadata.source.type === "CONTACT") { 
      // Pushing to that array, notice we use .children to push child items
      arr[a].children.push(this.k4kItems[a].person.names[b]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a more modern and elegant way of doing the same thing using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const arr = this.k4kItems.map(item => ({
    item,
    children: item.person.names.filter(
       name => name.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
    )
}))
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan Mendes. I am now having another problem. You code works great on names and emails, but when I try to add gender that same structure I get an undefined error.

Comment: const arr = this.k4kItems.map(item => ({
      resource_LBL: item.person.resourceName,
      names_lbl: item.person.names.filter(
        name_PARM => name_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
      ),
      email_LBL: item.person.emailAddresses.filter(
        email_PARM => email_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
      ),
      gender_LBL: item.person.genders.filter(
        gender_PARM => gender_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
      )
    }))

Comment: Uhoh. My comment above didn't work well. What is the correct way to handle is at Stack Overflow? He answered my question but not I have a new question about the answer. Is the right thing to do to mark this as answered and ask a new question, OR to continue to comment about the answer?

Comment: I went ahead and added a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916498/map-and-filter-works-on-two-array-elements-but-fails-on-a-third-that-is-seemingl

Comment: Yes, at SO each question should be a separate question so it's most helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that you push **arrays** in your `arr` array, means if `this.k4kItems[a].requestedResourceName` is not an array, you'll have that error.