# Map and Filter works on two array elements but fails on a third that is seemingly the same

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api

I have a promise from the Google People API. A **map** and **filter** that works on two elements perfectly, but gives an **undefined** error on a third element that seems the same to me.

I've read everything I can find on **map** and **filter** and taken educated guess for the last two hours. Neither approach seems to be advancing my efforts.

resource_LBL, names_LBL, and email_LBL works. The code fails on gender_LBL.

```
const arr = this.k4kItems.map(item => ({
  resource_LBL: item.person.resourceName,
  names_lbl: item.person.names.filter(
    name_PARM => name_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
  ),
  email_LBL: item.person.emailAddresses.filter(
    email_PARM => email_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
  ),
  gender_LBL: item.person.genders.filter(
    gender_PARM => gender_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
  )
}))
```

Below is the relevant elements or the promise with JSON.Stringify(promise).

```
"person": {
  "resourceName": "people\/c224283231105155344",
  "names": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "31cd0690f198110"
        }
      },
      "displayName": "Armena Kopf",
      "familyName": "Kopf",
      "givenName": "Armena",
      "displayNameLastFirst": "Kopf, Armena"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "112242108723070860293"
        }
      },
      "displayName": "Armena Dickson",
      "familyName": "Dickson",
      "givenName": "Armena",
      "displayNameLastFirst": "Dickson, Armena"
    }
  ],
  "genders": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "31cd0690f198110"
        }
      },
      "value": "female",
      "formattedValue": "Female"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "112242108723070860293"
        }
      },
      "value": "female",
      "formattedValue": "Female"
    }
  ],
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "31cd0690f198110"
        }
      },
      "value": "armena_d@yahoo.com",
      "type": "home",
      "formattedType": "Home"
    }
  ]
```

The expected result is that gender would map to the array instead of giving and **undefined** error.

Comment: is `this.k4kItems` json data that you posted?, because it seems object as it has key "person"

Comment: it works for me

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan according to Google's API docs it is a JSON. I used JSON.Stringify before posing because I have yet to figure out how to post console.log except as a picture.

Comment: Took a look at it, but it seems like it should work. You should modify https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/nb3sqo09/ (and move it to the runnable code feature here) so that the error happens

Comment: Works in the fiddle I created. You should modify it https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/nb3sqo09/ (and move it to the runnable code feature here) so that the error happens

Comment: Thank @JuanMendes. As soon as I figure out how to use jsfiddle.net (it's amazing) and the runnable feature on stack overflow I'll post a followup. It is Christmas Eve here and Atlanta and my wife is yelling threats if I do not get off the computer.

Comment: @JuanMendes I figured out my problem. I only pasted in the first record of the promise. In the very next 
**person,** gender does not exist for that person. It is, in fact, undefined. Do either of you know if there is a way to make a conditional filter (e.g. only apply the filter if the element exists in the promise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a check for the existence of deep properties that may not exist

```
gender_LBL: item.person.genders && item.person.genders.filter(
    gender_PARM => gender_PARM.metadata.source.type === "CONTACT"
)
```